# Stretch image outside container to end of page. Is calc() the only solution for that kind of layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have created a component where the image jumps out of the container and stretches to the end of the page. I used calc() to calculate all the offsets. Is this the only solution or are there other simpler variations to achieve this kind of layout? Important is that the solution aligns to the default container within the 12 grid inside. (Shown with the green box)

[image]

```
//vars
$lg: 1440px; //after this width the main-content no longer grows
$w-main-content: calc((11/12)*100vw); //91.666666666vw
$max-w-main-content: calc(#{$lg} * 11/12);  //1320px

//
// global classes
//

.w-main-content{
  width: #{$w-main-content};
  max-width: #{$max-w-main-content}
}

//calc margins for left and right
.ml-main-content{
  margin-left: calc((100vw - #{$w-main-content})/2)
}
.mr-main-content{
  margin-right: calc((100vw - #{$w-main-content})/2)
}

@media (min-width: $lg) {
  .ml-main-content{
    margin-left: calc((100vw - #{$max-w-main-content})/2)
  }
  .mr-main-content{
    margin-right: calc((100vw - #{$max-w-main-content})/2)
  }
}

//
// scoped classes for this component
//
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .img-width{
    width: calc((#{$w-main-content}/12*8) + (100vw - #{$w-main-content})/2)
  }
}

@media (min-width: $lg) {
  .img-width{
    width: calc((#{$max-w-main-content} / 12*8) + ((100vw - #{$max-w-main-content})/2))
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/OJRwYLW

this is a second version where I used translateX to push the image out of the box, but also used calc() to calculate the total width of the image and offset

https://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/jOMvNmK

Comment: Not the best way, but can be achieved by `absolute` positioning.

Comment: I'm only interested in better approaches ;)

Comment: ..........................................